# text-separator works with nth child, but doesn't with li + li for list items under unordered list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Code:**

```
<ul class="linkedd">
    <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>

    <li><a href='#about'>About</li>

    <li><a href='#portfolio'>Portfolio</li>

    <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</li>      
</ul>             

li:nth-child(n+2):before{
    content: " - ";
}
```

I had previously looked up this solution to add the dash separator from StackOverflow...however what didn't work for me as one user had suggested was

```
li + li:before {
    content: "/";
}
```

I understand how the `nth-child` works, and that it starts from 0 position and up so there is no dash in front of "home".  However what I don't understand is why `li + li:before` only gives me one dash (between home and about) and not the rest.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you aren't closing the `a` tag in the second `li` and the `li`'s afterwards

```css
li + li:before {
  content: "/";
}
/*demo */

li {
  float: left;
  list-style:none
}
```

```html
<ul class="linkedd">
  <li><a href='#home'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#about'>About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#portfolio'>Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```